# How to split array but No use loop

Tags: python, recursion

Determine if it possible to divide a list (lst) at some index such that the sum of values in the first part of the list equals the sum in the latter part of the list.
***No loops are used.***

```
def split_array2(lst, all_sum=0):
    first = split_array(lst[0:-1])
    last = lst[-1]


def sum_(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return 0
    return lst[0] + sum_[1:]
```

Comment: What *exactly* is the question? On what part of this algorithm are you having difficulty?

Comment: What is the relation between these two functions?

Comment: `sum(a)/2 in accumulate(a)`

Comment: @KellyBundy In this case, `sum(a)/2` is a float, and `in` tests for equality. Testing for equality of floats is usually a bad idea. This could be rewritten as `any(math.isclose((s := sum(a)/2), x) for x in accumulate(a))` if `a` is a list of floats; or `(s := sum(a)) % 2 == 0 and s//2 in accumulate(a)` for a list of ints.

Comment: @Stef The question says equals. If input were floats, they'd need to specify how handle inaccuracy. I assume ints, and only moderately large ones. That said, these things being unclear is why I posted it as comment, not an answer. Somewhat to elicit those things. Your first way is btw inefficient and you're not really using `s`.

Comment: @KellyBundy `sum(a)/2` is a float. Not an int. Even if every element in `a` is an int.

Comment: @Stef Yes, but is that a problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8]

def split_array(a, i=1): # changed to 1 to save 1 function call. AND to be sure that there is a valid split when sum(a)=0.
    if i == len(a):
        return False
    if sum(a[:i]) == sum(a[i:]):
        return i
    return split_array(a, i+1)

split_array(a)
>>> 5
#sum(a[:5]) = 15
#sum(a[5:]) = 15
```

This is a recursive function. Recursion is in a lot of cases an alternative to loops.

Comment: You should probably start from `i=1`, because if the sum of the initial array is 0, it will return a split of `[]` and `lst`

Comment: yes that will save you one function call, but indeed it is a little faster (but be sure to read that I said a little! :p ) But if performance is an issue one would probably not start at 1 but with a educated guess (like the middle and from there move left or right, but that depends if you know the data (like only positives or positive and negatives etc.)).

Comment: It's not only to save a function call.. I think it will also result in wrong output because I don't think that an empty array is a valid split :) (Assuming that negative numbers/only zeros is a valid input of course)

Comment: Yes it is and the function will give you the correct answer (as demonstrated). `sum([]) = 0`. But if you indeed if the sum of the whole array is zero you are definitely right and it is not a correct. Therefore I also edited my answer. Thank you for your feedback, it is appreciated.

Comment: You forgot to say the `sum` is a loop itself.

Comment: Yes you are right, but if you would like to go in that direction then you would say that vectorization is also a loop, but if you perform operations (for example on numpy arrays) it is a lot (A LOT) faster than a loop in python. Also one can create loops in `cython`, which also significantly improves performance. So technically you are right, but there are a lot of different loops in terms of performance.

Comment: Then the problem statement (specifically, the 'no loops' requirement) is vague.

Answer (score 0):

So something like this?

```
def canBeSplitted(lst,ind=1):
    if ind == len(lst):
        return false
    return sum(lst[0:ind]) == sum(lst(ind:)) || canBeSplitted(lst,ind+1)

canBeSplitted(lst) #usage
```

Answer (score 0):

There is always going to be some loops going on but you can hide them using recursion or library functions (if you're merely aiming to avoir the for/while constructs):

For example:

```
from itertools import accumulate
from bisect import bisect_right

def splitsum(lst):
    i = bisect_right([*accumulate(lst)],sum(lst)/2)
    return lst[:i],lst[i:]

L = [1,2,3,4,5,7,8]
print(*splitsum(L))
```

If you only need to determine if it is possible or not, you could return sum(lst[:i])==sum(lst[i:]) or better yet simply check if sum(lst)/2 is in accumulate(lst).